# How to print variables with rich console

Tags: python, rich

I want to print the series variable in bold and color it red after the user input is provided.

*This is the code I am currently using...*

```py
series = console.input("Search [bold cyan]Series[/] :earth_asia:\n> ")
console.print('Searching for [bold red] $(series) [/]')
```

*This is the actual output I see...*

```bash
Search Series 
> sample
Searching for $(series)
```

*This is the output I am expecting...*

```bash
Search Series 
> sample
Searching for sample
```

Comment: You need to use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) notation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `f-string` here:

```
from rich.console import Console

console = Console()

series = console.input("Search [bold cyan]Series[/] :earth_asia:\n> ")
console.print(f'Searching for [bold red] {series} [/]')
```

or you could do this:

```
console.print('Searching for [bold red] {} [/]'.format(series))
```